# What does “ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT” set to “Local” value in web.config mean

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables

Need to understand what does environment value “Local” mean? On loading .net core app,it was resulting in 500 error.. but on making environment variable entry in web.config with value set to “local”,made it work. Was wondering why?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: @Hackerman- above link doesnt mention anything about “Local” value..

Comment: Hackerman's comment is correct, and you should check where `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is used in your code. This `Local` should be your custom name.